# Angular 5 Upgrade - Module build failed: customPackage is not part of the compilation output

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am in the process of updating my Angular 4.4 project to Angular 5. I have followed the Angular Update Guide web app instructions, but am running in to an error that I have been unable to solve.

The following error is being output multiple times, for different module imports only among my personally created npm packages (all written in TypeScript).

`Module build failed: Error: /Users/username/Developer/parent-project/node_modules/custom-package-X/src/app/app-routing.module.ts is not part of the compilation output.`

I have three custom libraries imported, and similar errors are output for each of the three. These errors only occur for my custom packages; so it must have something to do with the way that I set them up.

I have a feeling that it is because my npm package is exposing the *TypeScript (.ts)* files, not the compiled *Javascript (.js)* files.

**Has anyone had similar issues, or have any suggestions?**

---

#### Dependency File Structure

```
/Users/username/Developer/custom-package-X
├── node_modules
|  ├── ...
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
|  ├── auth.service.ts
|  ├── authenticationtoken.ts
|  ├── authorizationtoken.ts
|  ├── resource.service.ts
|  ├── authentication-guard.service.ts
|  ├── authorization-guard.service.ts
|  └── index.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

**index.ts**

```
export { AuthService } from './auth.service';
export { ResourceService } from './resource.service';
export { AuthenticationToken } from './authenticationtoken';
export { AuthorizationToken } from './authorizationtoken';
export { AuthenticationGuard } from './authentication-guard.service';
export { AuthorizationGuard } from './authorization-guard.service';
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "lib": ["es2016", "DOM"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

**package.json**
*Nothing out of the ordinary, just some meta data and the stub for **test** script*.

Comment: Give this a look: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20091

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, in my case file name didn't match with import statement there was a capital letter ex: original file name is accountStatus.model.ts

Error in deploy statement but work fine in build:

```
import { AccountStatus } from './AccountStatus.model';
```

change file name statement:

```
import { AccountStatus } from './accountStatus.model';
```